# count the number of 3 consecutive days or more in R

Tags: r

I would like to count the number of times there are 3 consecutive days or more by year, give the number of consecutive days and take the maximum of temperature_max among these consecutive days and the date

Code :

```
date = c("2018-07-26", "2018-07-27", "2018-07-31", "2018-08-03", "2018-08-04", "2018-08-05", "2018-08-06", "2018-08-07", "2019-06-25", "2019-06-26", "2019-06-27", "2019-06-28", "2019-06-29", "2019-06-30", "2019-07-01", "2019-07-05", "2019-07-22", "2019-07-23", "2019-07-24", "2019-07-25", "2019-07-26", "2020-07-21", "2020-07-30", "2020-07-31", "2020-08-01", "2020-08-09", "2020-08-10", "2020-08-11", "2020-08-21")
temperature_min = c(19.8, 21.1, 21.2, 22.0, 24.1, 26.0, 22.2, 25.0, 21.6, 20.4, 20.6, 24.8, 21.3, 24.7, 22.6, 19.6, 22.3, 21.2, 24.8, 24.6, 21.3, 21.5, 20.1, 22.3, 21.7, 19.4, 20.7, 20.6, 24.7)
temperature_max = c(34.7, 36.2, 34.6, 34.9, 36.7, 35.9, 35.8, 35.1, 35.1, 36.6, 38.1, 35.5, 37.6, 36.7, 35.3, 35.2, 34.6, 38.5, 39.7, 39.0, 36.7, 34.5, 37.2, 39.4, 36.4, 37.2, 36.8, 36.4, 35.7) 
data = as.data.frame(cbind(date, temperature_min, temperature_max ))
```

[image]

For example In 2018, there are 1 time 3 consecutive days (from August 3 to 7), i.e. 5 days and the temperature_max = 36.4 (4 august). In 2019 there are 2 time 3 consecutive days (from June 25 to July 1st), i.e.  days and the temperature_max = 38.1 (June 27) and 5 days (from August 22 to 26) with max = 39.7 (August 24). In 2020 are 2 time 3 consecutive days too (from july 30 to August 1st), i.e. 3 days and the temperature_max = 39.4 (July 31) and 3 days (from August 9 to 11) with max = 37.2 (August 9)

So I want as a result

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a probable `dplyr` solution -

```
library(dplyr)

data %>%
  mutate(date = as.Date(date),
         year = lubridate::year(date),
         group = cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(date) > 1))) %>%
  group_by(year, group) %>%
  filter(n() >= 3) %>%
  summarise(start = min(date), 
            duration = n(), 
            max = max(temperature_max), 
            date_of_max = date[which.max(temperature_max)], .groups = 'drop') %>%
  select(-group)

#   year start      duration   max date_of_max
#  <int> <date>        <int> <dbl> <date>     
#1  2018 2018-08-03        5  36.7 2018-08-04 
#2  2019 2019-06-25        7  38.1 2019-06-27 
#3  2019 2019-07-22        5  39.7 2019-07-24 
#4  2020 2020-07-30        3  39.4 2020-07-31 
#5  2020 2020-08-09        3  37.2 2020-08-09
```

**data**

```
data = data.frame(date, temperature_min, temperature_max )
```